# cause of file i/o operation failure = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)

Tags: linux, files, permissions, sudo, io

I'm in the middle of a bug in my program and I've narrowed it down with usage of strace to the following error -

```
open("/sys/class/gpio/gpio17/value", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_LARGEFILE, 0666) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
open("/sys/class/gpio/gpio17/direction", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_LARGEFILE, 0666) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
```

For background information, you can read this thread here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39524234/bug-with-writing-to-file-in-linux-sys-class-gpio

I've 3 seperate runs of my test, one normal, one with sudo specified and another with intentional delay specified. Here are the relevant strace outcomes of those runs -

**`Normal`**

```
open("/sys/class/gpio/export", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_LARGEFILE, 0666) = 3
open("/sys/class/gpio/unexport", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_LARGEFILE, 0666) = 3
open("/sys/class/gpio/export", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_LARGEFILE, 0666) = 3
open("/sys/class/gpio/gpio17/value", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_LARGEFILE, 0666) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
open("/sys/class/gpio/gpio17/direction", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_LARGEFILE, 0666) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
open("/sys/class/gpio/unexport", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_LARGEFILE, 0666) = 3
```

**`sudo`**

```
open("/sys/class/gpio/export", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_LARGEFILE, 0666) = 3
open("/sys/class/gpio/unexport", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_LARGEFILE, 0666) = 3
open("/sys/class/gpio/export", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_LARGEFILE, 0666) = 3
open("/sys/class/gpio/gpio17/value", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_LARGEFILE, 0666) = 3
open("/sys/class/gpio/gpio17/direction", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_LARGEFILE, 0666) = 4
open("/sys/class/gpio/unexport", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_LARGEFILE, 0666) = 3
```

**`Delayed`**

```
("/sys/class/gpio/export", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_LARGEFILE, 0666) = 3
open("/sys/class/gpio/unexport", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_LARGEFILE, 0666) = 3
open("/sys/class/gpio/export", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_LARGEFILE, 0666) = 3
open("/sys/class/gpio/gpio17/value", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_LARGEFILE, 0666) = 3
open("/sys/class/gpio/gpio17/direction", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_LARGEFILE, 0666) = 4
open("/sys/class/gpio/unexport", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_LARGEFILE, 0666) = 3
```

Now I've tried searching for this [error](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=EACCES%20(Permission%20denied)), but all I find is javascript,android or nodejs errors with no link to original description. Any kind of information would be utmost beneficial to me, so thanks for your help :)

**EDIT** - If it's relevant, I've this as udev rule in `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-com.rules` -

```
SUBSYSTEM=="bcm2835-gpiomem", KERNEL=="gpiomem", GROUP="gpio", MODE="0660"
SUBSYSTEM=="gpio", KERNEL=="gpiochip*", ACTION=="add", PROGRAM="/bin/sh -c 'chown root:gpio /sys/class/gpio/export /sys/class/gpio/unexport ; chmod 220 /sys/class/gpio/export /sys/class/gpio/unexport'"
SUBSYSTEM=="gpio", KERNEL=="gpio*", ACTION=="add", PROGRAM="/bin/sh -c 'chown root:gpio /sys%p/active_low /sys%p/direction /sys%p/edge /sys%p/value ; chmod 660 /sys%p/active_low /sys%p/direction /sys%p/edge /sys%p/value'"
```

and ls -l output -

```
total 0
--w--w---- 1 root gpio 4096 Sep 16 07:13 export
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Sep 16 07:13 gpio17 -> ../../devices/platform/soc/3f200000.gpio/gpio/gpio17
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Jul 31 05:23 gpiochip0 -> ../../devices/platform/soc/3f200000.gpio/gpio/gpiochip0
--w--w---- 1 root gpio 4096 Sep 16 06:50 unexport
```

current user is part of gpio group as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd be willing to put money on this being a race condition between your program and `udev`.

Apparently, the `/sys/class/gpio/gpio17/value` and `/sys/class/gpio/gpio17/direction` nodes are created at some point after `open("/sys/class/gpio/export", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_LARGEFILE, 0666) = 3`, and initially they're probably owned by `root:root`, with no write access for your regular user.

Then the udev rule kicks in and udev calls sh to set the permissions, but that takes a while; if you try the next `open()` before, it fails.

I don't know if there is a way for you to wait for udev to finish without polling.

Comment: If you happen know udev is in the middle of changing itself you can wait for `udevadm settle` (see http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/udevadm.8.html ) to complete as the current queue of events will now be empty.